# how can i access All application which is using INTERNET in Android

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, 5.0-lollipop

i want to access all application which is using Internet at the background of our mobile phone kindly help me how to find applications which is running on Internet at background.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Your question is somewhat unclear. What do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "access"? Something like you find in *Settings › Data Usage* (where foreground and background usage is listed explicitly)?

Answer (score 0):

It can be found in Settings > Data Usage.

Below the data usage graph, you can see all the applications that have used Internet for the last month.

If you tap on an app, you can also see how much of its the data it used was in the background.